# Stencil buffer depth in OpenTK

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk, tao-framework

I`m using OpenTK for OpenGL and C#.

I need to use stencil buffer and currently wondering how do I set `StencilBuffer` depth.

As I know earlier was TaoFramework and it`s control had property where this depth could be seted.

But now in openGlControl from OpenTK I can not find such property. As I know current seted buffer depth can be obtained by calling `GL.GetInteger()` method passing to it special parameter.
And when I do so it returns 0. This means that currently stencil buffer depth is zero, so any operations won"t have result untill some buffer depth is seted. But I can`t find out how to do this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Don't forget to award the bounty by clicking the blue box under the tick!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you set it up when you create the graphics context:

http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/graphicscontext

Close to the top of that document it gives the following example:

```
// Creates a 3.0-compatible GraphicsContext with 32bpp color, 24bpp depth
// 8bpp stencil and 4x anti-aliasing.
GLControl control = new GLControl(new GraphicsMode(32, 24, 8, 4), 3, 0);
```

This is typical -- OpenGL basically punts this sort of thing to the OS-specific context creation task... So if you weren't using OpenTK for example you'd have to set this up with wgl and the windows api.